# How best to mount a drive in WSL as a shared drive?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, wsl2, fstab, automount

I'm trying to simplify/automate my development environment in Windows, I have a lot of shell files I run on both Windows and the Linux subsystem, I've recently taken to editing my `/etc/wsl.conf` to setting

```
[automount]
root = /
```

This makes my path to windows /c/... instead of /mnt/c/... which has simplified file access across many of my scripts allowing scripts to call from host to wsl or back again and allowing me to implement automation seamlessly in both environments. my problem is after every bootup of wsl I also need to run `sudo mount --make-shared /c/`
so that my scripts can reach across to the other system properly, I know I can use the `mountFsTab` but of all the things I'm pretty amateur with The Fstab file and haven't moded one in some time, not to mention with it under wsl, and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to set up my /c/ mount as a shared drive so I have simple 2-way communication, and don't waste time cause I forgot to run the make-shared command before getting to work, then being confused about my set up?
If there is also a different way than using the Fstab, but just configuring the wsl.conf that would be even better, I just didn't find anything on Microsoft's documentation about doing this simply. Anyway, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: @l4t3nc1 I disagree.  Although the question is in the context of a development workflow, it's definitely a "General Computing" (OS) question that we would likely close on Stack Overflow.  While folks on the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) might have more expertise around this particular use-case, it's probably most appropriate right here due to the mix of WSL/Windows/Linux functionality under discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your use-case for remounting at `/` or using shared mounts, but I'd really like to.  I'm going to answer with my current understanding of your question, but I would love to see you edit it to provide more detail on the use-case.

It's entirely possible there may be some better options for your workflow.

That said, your core question appears pretty straightforward:

To summarize:

> How can I best persist a shared mount in WSL?

As you've noticed, Windows drives are mounted by the WSL `/init` rather than `/etc/fstab`.  And while there's *some* control via `/etc/wsl.conf` over the mount options (e.g. the actual mount point, `uid`/`gid`), the `shared` mount propagation is not one of those options.

You have several options:

- Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` which remounts the drive with the `shared` option.  I find it easiest to do this by copying the current mount table entry from `/etc/mtab` into `/etc/fstab`:

  ```
  grep "/c " /etc/mtab | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
  ```

  Of course, testing the `grep` first might be a good idea before copying it, just to make sure that it returns the line you want.

  Then edit `/etc/fstab` and add `shared` to the beginning of the options.  For instance, immediately before the `rw` option.

  You'll need to exit WSL, `wsl --terminate <distro>`, and restart in order to get it to take effect, but I can confirm that this worked for starting WSL with the drive mounted as shared.
- If you just want to run `mount --make-shared /c/` at WSL startup, there are two additional options.  First, for Windows 11, you can add the following to your `/etc/wsl.conf`:

  ```
  [boot]
  command="mount --make-shared /c/"
  ```

  If you need to run multiple commands, join them with a semicolon in a single `command=` string.

  This command runs as `root` at WSL startup, so no need to `sudo` or enter a password.
- If you don't have (and can't currently upgrade) to Windows 11, you can always add the command to your `~/.bash_profile` (or other applicable startup file).  There's a neat trick here that can keep you from having to use `sudo` as well.  Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  wsl.exe -u root -e mount --make-shared /c/
  ```

  That runs WSL with the root user and executes the `mount` command.

  *Important Note*:  If you are scripting WSL, you may end up running other commands like this from PowerShell, CMD, or other scripts.  When executed with a command (non-interactively), WSL does *not* typically run the shell as a login or interactive shell.  So, if you have scripts that run that need `~/.bash_profile` (or other startup files) to be loaded, make sure to run them with `wsl.exe -e bash -lic "command"`.  This will run the command in a bash shell that is both "login" (sources profile scripts) and "interactive" (sources rc scripts).

Note that I have confirmed these work via:

```
findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /mnt/c # /c/ in your case, of course

TARGET PROPAGATION
/mnt/c shared
```

After testing, I disabled the option, terminated the instance, and rechecked to make sure the propagation was back to `private`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this in-depth answer. I keep a lot of my data/files on my windows partition so when mounted at /c/ excluding windows to posix path translation all the locations I need to access are unified. I do happen to be on Windows 11 at this time, and option 2 worked perfectly for me. And I'm glad to know a little more about how initiated systems work under the hood in wsl, I'll likely benefit from that elsewhere.

Comment: I know that systemd will mount / as shared (i.e. mount propagation) by default, so I guess that's why WSL doesn't do that (since it doesn't run systemd). But do you know if there are any security implications or performance issues to consider before making `/` shared?